# Solve $\int_{A} \frac{x^2y + y^3 - y}{x^2 + y^2} \, dx + \frac{x^3 + xy^2 + x}{x^2 + y^2} \, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, greens-theorem

Solve $\displaystyle
\int_{A} \frac{x^2y + y^3 - y}{x^2 + y^2} \, dx
       + \frac{x^3 + xy^2 + x}{x^2 + y^2} \, dy
       $ , $A$ is the unit circle.

My attempt:

$\displaystyle
\int_{A} \frac{x^2y + y^3 - y}{x^2 + y^2} \, dx
       + \frac{x^3 + xy^2 + x}{x^2 + y^2} \, dy
       =\int_A ydx+xdy-(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}dy)=\displaystyle\int_A ydx+xdy+\int_A(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}dy)$

First,using Green's theorem  $\displaystyle\int_A ydx+xdy =0 $.

Second, $\int_A(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}dy)$

Denote $x=\cos\theta,y=\sin\theta \implies dx=-\sin\theta,dy=\cos\theta$.

Therefore , $\int_A(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}dy)=\int_0^{2\pi}-sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=0$

$\displaystyle
\int_{A} \frac{x^2y + y^3 - y}{x^2 + y^2} \, dx
       + \frac{x^3 + xy^2 + x}{x^2 + y^2} \, dy=0$

My answer isn't correct , can't find out what I am doing , appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a sign mistake. You should have that
$$\int_{A} \frac{x^2y + y^3 - y}{x^2 + y^2} \, \mathrm{d}x+ \frac{x^3 + xy^2 + x}{x^2 + y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y=I_1+I_2\, ,$$
where
$$I_1=\int_A \left(y~\mathrm{d}x+x~\mathrm{d}y\right)\, ,$$
$$I_2=\int_A \left(\color{red}{-}\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}~\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}~\mathrm{d}y\right)\, .$$
As you correctly noted, $I_1=0$ by Green's theorem. You can compute $I_2$ either by using the same method you have tried, i.e. using the parametrisation $x=\cos(\theta)$, $y=\sin(\theta)$, or by simply noting that
$$-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}~\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}~\mathrm{d}y=\mathrm{d}\left(\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right).$$